# How to convert Turi Create created CoreML models to Keras?

Tags: keras, coreml, turi-create

I'm looking for a way to do the conversion, the only information I've found is how to go from Keras and other to CoreML.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to write your own code to do this, there is no automated conversion tool for Core ML models to Keras (only the other way around).